# How to optimize Static Assets on an Hybrid App

Tags: android, ios, performance, backbone.js, webview

I have an Hybrid Web App using Backbone.js and around 20 vendor libs (JQuery, Paper.js, …). This web app is used directly on different browsers, inside a webview in Android and inside a webview in iOS (not the latest iOS webview WKWebView).

I try to optimize static assets delivery to avoid latency in iOS and Android app.
On production I create 3 bundles: 
- 1 for my JS files (383kB)
- 1 for all vendor JS files (918kB)
- 1 for my CSS files and for vendor CSS files (209kB)

Every bundle is minified and versioned.

I would like to know if this is more efficient to use directly vendor files from their CDN or to the large vendor bundle from my CDN?

By serving 3 bundles from my CDN, I am reducing the number of requests but loading and parsing this huge file takes time.
By calling each vendor from their CDN, I make 1 request per file, but most visitor already have JQuery and some other libs in memory, so they won't download it again.

What is the best approach to optimize for Webviews?

Comment: You should utilize the AppCache API to store all those assets locally the first time your app is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat this situation the same way you would a regular webpage that is optimized for mobile. First, ~1.5MBs for your JS and CSS assets is high if your target audience is mobile. Not only do older devices parse JS and CSS slower, network latency is an issue as well. If at all possible, try to trim down the number of libraries you use. For example, you may not need all of JQuery and could get by with a smaller library like [zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/).

Chances are your visitors will only have the most popular libraries in their cache (jQuery, Backbone, etc). More niche libraries, such as Paper.js will probably need to be loaded regardless. On top of that, you will need to use multiple CDNs to deliver your content, since less popular libraries like Paper.js won't be hosted on Google or the like. This means you are relying on more third-parties. So in this case I would serve all of your assets from your own servers. Preferably you could serve your files from a CDN like [Cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/).